# Entity Framework error - Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (Index) is wrong

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to delete few existing columns of 2 tables using code first approach, when I am running the command

```
update-database -Verbose
```

in the Nuget package manager console I get the exception shown.

```
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'euts.PRODUCT.IX_ID_PRODUCT_PARENT', 
                  @newname = N'IX_PRODUCT_PARENT_ID_PRODUCT', 
                  @objtype = N'INDEX'
```

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (Index) is wrong

I have a table called `PRODUCT` and that table has a columns `ID_PRODUCT`, `ID_PRODUCT_PARENT`. The `ID_PRODUCT_PARENT` has foreign key relationship with `ID_PRODUCT` column of the same `PRODUCT` table.

I am trying to delete `ID_PRODUCT_PARENT` column from the `PRODUCT` table.

I also modified the below line of code in the `DbContext` class by removing the

```
HasForeignKey(x => ID_PRODUCT_PARENT)
```

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PRODUCT>()
       .HasOptional(e => e.PRODUCT_PARENT)
       .WithMany(e => e.PRODUCT_CHILDREN)
       .HasForeignKey(x => ID_PRODUCT_PARENT)
```

Going by the SQL command which EF has generated its trying to rename INDEX, when I checked the SQL Server database, there is no INDEX on `PRODUCT` table with name `IX_ID_PRODUCT_PARENT`, not sure why Entity Framework generated a SQL query that is trying to rename `Index` when I am trying to drop columns.

I am expecting to drop columns and also the foreign key constraint of `ID_PRODUCT_PARENT` on `PRODUCT` Table.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this exception ?

Note - the Entity Framework generated SQL commands have code to drop the columns I wanted but the 2nd line of the code is

```
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'euts.PRODUCT.IX_ID_PRODUCT_PARENT', 
                  @newname = N'IX_PRODUCT_PARENT_ID_PRODUCT', 
                  @objtype = N'INDEX'
```

which is causing the exception, after this line it has the SQL code to drop the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF Code First works fine if nobody modifies the database structure from outside EF.

Mixing Code First with manually modifying the database is not a good idea, because conflicts as the one your having may arise.

The reason why EF is trying to drop an index is because the column that your trying to delete has an index (in EF previous database model). So it will first delete the index and the drop the column.

The reason why are you having this disconnect between EF model and the SQL model is because either the database was not created with EF Code First or someo manually dropped the index in the database.

I see two solutions:

- Regenerate the EF model using the scaffold command. This will Regenerate all your c# classes based on the database definition. It can be quite difficult to then adapt the code to make it work again.
- Manually add the index to the database so the migration can run successfully. The biggest risk here is that you don't know what else might be different between EF model and SQL model, so you may encounter additional issues down the road.